# terminate the background task launched by xterminal

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, script, xorg

I used Xterm -e command to run six programs in the background in six X terminals in my shell script. When I used PS command, I can see 6 Xterm process running in the background but I can't see the programs. If I used Top command, I can see the programs. Is there a clean way to kill all the x terminals and the programs?

Here is the xterminal command in my script:

```
xterm -e "script -c \"program\" outputfile" &
```

Another problem is I try to capture the output of the program to a file, but for some reason I can only capture part of it. If I get rid of the `&` at the end, I can capture all the output but I can't get control back since the program is running as a server, which means it doesn't end unless I kill the server.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` without arguments/options displays only processes connected to the current terminal. Anything you run in a new `xterm` will have that `xterm`'s pseudotty as its controlling terminal.

You can usually get away with killing the `xterm`s to kill the programs running in them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did close all the xterms. But top still shows those processing are running.

Answer (score 0):

These three links may be of interest:

1. [pgrep and pkill](http://198.62.75.4/opt/sun_docs/C/solaris_10/SUNWabe/ADVOSUG/p16.html) - Solaris specific page
2. [This page on window process management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3197/3046) on U&L
3. The [Process Chain](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch24_20.htm) at docstore